# Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, htmlagilitypack

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: работал на версии HAP 1.11.23, всё работало, проект запускался из папки Release. После того, как я передал exe-файл и библиотеку HAP на другой компьютер, он перестал запускаться. Просил библиотеку HAP версии 1.5.1.0. Я откатился до версии 1.5.1.0, скомпилировал проект в Release. Теперь, когда я передаю его на другой компьютер он снова требует библиотеку, но уже более низкой версии 1.4.6.

Я попробовал также откатить до 1.4.6, но тогда проект снова просит 1.5.1.0.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Библиотека то есть рядом с .exe файлом?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Библиотека есть

Comment: Может у второго компьютера версия фреймворка не такая как у вас?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение заключалось в простом: вместе с библиотекой HAP я использовал ещё Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack, после её обновления до последней версии, всё начало работать.